# Windows SC.exe how to query control codes on a service

Tags: c#, windows, service, sc.exe

**What I Have Done**

I am trying to implement `ServiceBase.OnCustomCommand(int command)` in a custom Windows Service called `MyTestService`, with custom command codes as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17406035/11163122):

```
public enum MyCustomCommands { ExecuteScript = 128 };
```

I noticed it's common to start custom command values at `128`.

---

I attempted to implement custom command codes like so:

```
public enum MyCustomCommandCodes
{
    Test1 = 1,
    Test2 = 2,
}

protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
    switch (command)
    {
        case (int)MyCustomCommandCodes.Test1:
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Test1");
            break;
        case (int)MyCustomCommandCodes.Test2:
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Test2");
            break;
        default:
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("default");
            break;
    }
}
```

I am calling `OnCustomCommand` using Window's command-line utility [Service Control (SC)](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html).

When I enter `sc control MyTestService 1`, I found instead of calling case `Test1`, it actually stopped the service.

In my mind, this explains why people start command values at `128`, it's to prevent overlap with codes already in use.

---

I would like to be able to see which control codes are already in use by a Windows service.

**Two-part Question**:

- Is there a way to query the list of all codes that are in use?
- If yes, is there also a way to query what each code actually does?

Comment: This might answer both questions in this post, as well as the other question you posted: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @madreflection's comment, which points out the `ControlService` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice

User-defined control code range: `128 to 255`.

And it also states why `sc control MyTestService 1` stops the service, it's because `0x1` corresponds with the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` control code.

---

This answers my question from a different direction, with a lookup table given by Microsoft.