# WCF service trying to run a Powershell script to Remote in on a different machine

Tags: c#, powershell, wcf

I'm trying to run the following scrip on my WCF service hosted on my computer.

```
string exePath = "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
            var ps1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
            ps1.FileName = exePath;
            ps1.Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\\Users\\fn070084\\Desktop\\Test2.ps1";
            ps1.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
            Process.Start(ps1);
```

If I run just this code, it runs correctly on Visual studio, but when I put it on a service on the WCF server it's not doing something.

The code for the Test2 File is this one

```
$LogFile = "\\ComputerName\C$\powershellLog" + $LongTime + ".txt" "Hello, I'm running Powershell through C#" >>$logFile
```

Note: I wrote it as "ComputerName" but on my actual code I'm having the the rigth computer name.

Answer (score 0):

First ,make sure that the server on which the WCF Service is installed is able to access and invoke the service, as you can see in [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

In addition, your own computer should be able to communicate with the server, the call method can be accessed. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397324/it-is-possible-to-communicate-to-windows-service-from-wcf).